# Trying to predict running time of algorithms through regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, or-tools

I'm following this paper:
http://robotics.stanford.edu/users/shoham/www%20papers/Empirical%20Hardness.pdf

and I try to predict the running time for the Traveling salesman problem on a blackbox solver.

I get some weird results during regression that I'd love to consult about:

1. I find it hard to believe that in XGBOOST or at any regessor the number of cities is irrelevant as a feature? as seen in XGBOOST feature importance image.
2. In the RIDGE and LINEAR REGRESSION results graphs you can see that for some problem instances the graphs you can see that the predicted value is negative (when we talk about run time), I saw in other question here that this is because "Linear regression does not respect the bounds of 0" and that I should put a natural log on it, but I don't know exactly where. So I'd love help with that also.
3. I'd also love to be reccomended on other regression models that may fit my problem.

Thanks a lot!

Here is my code pieces (google colab), followed by the results I got:

1
# Import the standard libraries of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings. filterwarnings("ignore")
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
from google.colab import files
```

2
# Install the solver and import its libraries, in addition import all the
# libraries with which we will prepare the features.

```
!pip3 install ortools 
!pip install python-igraph

from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

import numpy as np
import time
import random 
from random import randrange
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import skew
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import minimum_spanning_tree
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import depth_first_tree
from igraph import Graph, mean
import igraph
import itertools
import math
```

3
# Simple travelling salesman problem between cities - solver OR Tools By Google.

```
def create_data_model():
    # Stores the data for the problem. 
    data = {}
    # dim will be the number of Vertices\Cities in the Traveling Salesman Problem.
    # Randomly select the matrix dimension in unifom distribution.
    dim = np.random.randint(10, 350) 
    # Generate a square symmetric matrix It will be the distance matrix that the solver will solve.
    square_matrice = [[0 for row in range(dim)] for col in range(dim)]
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if i == j:
                square_matrice[i][j] = 0
            else:
                # Randomly fill the matrix in unifom distribution.
                square_matrice[i][j] = square_matrice[j][i] = np.random.randint(1, 1000) 
    data['distance_matrix'] = square_matrice # yapf: disable
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def main():
    # Start measuring solution time.
    start_time = time.time()
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        # Returns the distance between the two nodes. 
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    solution_time = time.time() - start_time

    '''In this part of the code we will create the following features on the distance matrix of the problem.
    *  Mean - Average weights of the distance matrix.
    *  Std - Standard Deviation of the distance matrix.
    *  Skewness  - What is the tendency of the weights in the distance matrix.
    *  Noc - Number of cities we have in the distance matrix [matrix dimension].
    *  Td - The total distance of the solution rout. 
    *  Dmft - Distance matrix features time, That is how long it took us to calculate all these features.
    '''
    dmt_start_time = time.time()
    mat = np.array(data['distance_matrix'])
    mean = mat.mean()
    std = mat.std()
    merged = list(itertools.chain(*mat))
    skewness = skew(merged)
    noc = len(data['distance_matrix'])
    td = solution.ObjectiveValue() if solution else -1
    dmft = time.time() - dmt_start_time

    '''In this part of the code we will create from the distance matrix of the problem an MST and than
    on the MST we take the following features.
    *  MST_Mean - Average weights of the MST.
    *  MST_Std - Standard Deviation of the MST.
    *  MST_Skewness  - What is the tendency of the weights in the MST.
    *  MST_ft - MST features time, That is how long it took us to calculate the MST & all these features.
    '''
    spt_start_time = time.time()
    X = csr_matrix(mat)
    Tcsr = minimum_spanning_tree(X)
    mat_st = np.array(Tcsr.toarray().astype(int))
    mst_mean = mat_st.mean()
    mst_std = mat_st.std()
    merged_st = list(itertools.chain(*mat_st))
    mst_skewness = skew(merged_st)
    mst_ft = time.time() - spt_start_time

    '''In this part of the code we calculate features from the MST that are considered to be
    related to the rank and depth of the tracks in it.
    *  D_Mean - Average degree of the MST.
    *  D_Std - Standard Deviation of the MST degrees.
    *  D_Skewness  - What is the tendency of the degrees in the MST.
    *  DFT_Mean - The average weight of the deepest track in MST.
    *  DFT_Std - Standard Deviation of the deepest track in MST.
    *  DFT_Max - The heaviest arch on the longest route in MST.
    *  DDFT_ft - Degree & DFT features time, That is how long it took us to calculate all these features.
    '''
    dstt_start_time = time.time()
    g = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(mat_st.tolist())
    d_mean = igraph.statistics.mean(g.degree())
    d_std = igraph.statistics.sd(g.degree())
    d_skewness = skew(g.degree())
    d_t = depth_first_tree(X, 0, directed=False)
    mat_dt = np.array(d_t.toarray().astype(int))
    dft_mean = mat_dt.mean()
    dft_std = mat_dt.std()
    dft_max = np.amax(mat_dt)
    ddft_ft = time.time() - dstt_start_time

    # In this map we will hold all the features and their results.
    features_map = {'Mean': mean, 'Std': std, 'Skewness': skewness, 'Noc': noc, 'Td': td, 'Dmft': dmft,
                    'MST_Mean': mst_mean, 'MST_Std': mst_std, 'MST_Skewness': mst_skewness, 'MST_ft': mst_ft,
                    'D_Mean': d_mean, 'D_Std': d_std, 'D_Skewness': d_skewness, 'DFT_Mean': dft_mean,'DFT_Std': dft_std,
                    'DFT_Max': dft_max, 'DDFT_ft': ddft_ft, 'Solution_time': solution_time}

    return features_map

# Main    
# Create dataFrame.
data_TSP = pd.DataFrame()
# Fill the dataFrame.
for i in range(10000):
    #print(i)
    features_map = main()
    data_TSP = data_TSP.append(features_map, ignore_index=True) 
# Show data frame.

data_TSP.head()
data_TSP.to_csv('data_10000.csv')
files.download('data_10000.csv')
```

Regression models:

```
# Import the standard libraries of pandas.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings. filterwarnings("ignore")
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
```

2
# Neaded for opening data file in drive.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data_10000_clean.csv']))
try:
    df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace=True) 
except: 
    pass
df.head()
```

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
# Split the data to training set and test set (70%, 30%)
features = list(df.drop('Solution_time', axis = 1, inplace = False))
y = df['Solution_time']
X = df[features]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
```

## Import models which we predicted with tham the solution,

## And scoring methods to evaluate these models.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import linear_model
!pip3 install xgboost
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
!pip install scikit-plot
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib as mpl

########################################## Several functions for different regression  models. ##########################################

class Score:

    r2 = 0.0                   # This score determines how close the predictions really are to the real data.
    cross_vali_score = 0.0     # How true is our algorithm if it going to well predict new data.

class Regressor:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = Score()
        self.y_pred = None
        self.reg = None

# Map between the name of a model and the model itself.
models_map = {'Random Forest': RandomForestRegressor(), 'Xgboost': XGBRegressor(), 'Ridge': Ridge(), 
              'Kneighbors': KNeighborsRegressor(), 'Linear Regressor': linear_model.LinearRegression()}

# This function return a map that maps between each model and its Regressor class.
def get_models():
    result_map = {}
    for key, val in models_map.items():
        result = Regressor(key)
        reg = val
        result.score.cross_vali_score = np.mean(cross_val_score(reg, X_train, y_train, cv=5))        
        result.reg = reg.fit(X_train, y_train) 
        result.y_pred = reg.predict(X_test) 
        result.score.r2 = r2_score(y_test, result.y_pred) 
        result_map[key] = result 
    return result_map

# This function print a graph for models of the features that influenced their decision making.
def print_influence_graph(map):
    for key, val in map.items():
        if key == 'Random Forest' or key == 'Xgboost':
            # The parameters that most influenced the decision.
            feature_imp = pd.Series(val.reg.feature_importances_,index=features).sort_values(ascending=False)
            sns.barplot(x=feature_imp, y=feature_imp.index)
            # Add labels to your graph
            plt.xlabel('Feature Importance Score')
            plt.ylabel('Features')
            plt.title(val.name.upper() +" - Visualizing Important Features")
            plt.show()

# This function print a graph for models that show the real results against the model predictions.
def show_predicted_vs_actual(map):
    for key, val in map.items():
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.scatter(y_test, val.y_pred, edgecolors=(0, 0, 1))
        ax.plot([y_test.min(), y_test.max()], [y_test.min(), y_test.max()], 'r--', lw=3)
        ax.set_xlabel('Predicted')
        ax.set_ylabel('Actual')
        ax.title.set_text(val.name.upper() +" - Predicted time vs actual time")
        plt.show()

# This function print numerical scores for the models.
def print_scores(map):
    for key, val in map.items():
        print(val.name.upper() + ' SCORE: ')
        print('R2score' + '  =  ', val.score.r2)
        print('Cross_val_score' + '  =  ', val.score.cross_vali_score)
        print('------------------------------------------\n')

# This function print a graph showing the differences between the scores of the models.
def show_models_differences_graph(map):
    comp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ('Method', 'R2 Score', 'Cross val score'))
    for i in map:
        row = {'Method': i, 'R2 Score': map[i].score.r2, 'Cross val score': map[i].score.cross_vali_score}
        comp_df = comp_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    ax = comp_df.plot.bar(x='Method', rot=30, figsize=(12,6))
    ax.set_title('Comparison graph')   
#########################################################################################################################################

models = get_models()
print_influence_graph(models)
show_predicted_vs_actual(models)
print_scores(models)
show_models_differences_graph(models)
```

And here are the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can imagine those top 3 features correlate a lot with a plain N (node count), but probably have more color about difficulty of problem. They are just good proxies to get a sense of N, and the models dont see a need to have the N as additional feature.